# Resharper - How to change 'local variable _ is never used' to be a suggestion

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper, resharper-4.5

I need to change this to be a suggestion and not a warning, but I cannot find the setting to do so.

Where is it?

This is the code that needs to pass (not a compilier warning). It is saying that transaction is a local variable that is not used, but this is valid.

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need transaction variable, you can replace it with 
using (new TransactionScope())
{
}

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ReSharper lets you turn things into a suggestion that will result in a compiler warning or error. I believe this is by design.

Comment: updated with an example of what is being flagged as a warning, is this a bug with R#?

Comment: Ilya is correct. In your example, the variable isn't needed at all, using(new TransactionScope()) is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the headline of the question (not the specific example).

For (8.2.1):

> 1) ReSharper -> Options -> Potential Code Quality Issues
>
> 2) Enter "Unused Local" in search, a few lines will show up.
>
> The levels can be adjusted on the right.

If I knew how to change that particular color it uses (bad against black background) instead of disabling the warning entirely I would post that also but its having a hard time tracing which element it is (wondering if its even there).  Anyone?